# ListView não exibe os dados carregados do BD

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Tenho uma tela de consulta, onde ela deveria exibir os itens já cadastrados.
Só que não exibe. 
Primeiramente, achei que era porque as informações não estavam sendo gravadas no BD, mas elas estão.
Só que, não achei o porquê delas não serem carregadas... imagino que seja alguma coisa que não fiz, mas não estou sabendo o que é.

**ConsCliente.java**

```
package br.sysandroid;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import br.sysandroid.dao.banco.BancoDAO; 
import br.sysandroid.model.Cliente;
import br.sysandroid.dao.ClienteAdapter;
import br.sysandroid.dao.ClienteDAO;

public class ConsCliente extends ListActivity {

private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;
List<Cliente> clientes;
ClienteAdapter adapter;
BancoDAO bancoDAO;
int posicao = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.conscliente);
    bancoDAO = new BancoDAO(this);

    Button btCadastro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btCadastro);
    btCadastro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(ConsCliente.this, CadCliente.class));
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    clienteDAO = new ClienteDAO(this);
    clienteDAO.open();
    clientes = clienteDAO.lerClientes();

    adapter = new ClienteAdapter(this, clientes);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    super.onResume();
    }
}
```

**conscliente.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="291dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btCadastro"
            android:text="Cadastro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btSair"
            android:text="Sair"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**ClienteAdapter.java**

```
package br.sysandroid.dao;

import java.util.List;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import br.sysandroid.R.id;
import br.sysandroid.R.layout;
import br.sysandroid.model.Cliente;

public class ClienteAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

    private List<Cliente> clientes;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ClienteAdapter(Context context, List<Cliente> clientes) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.clientes = clientes;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        try {
            super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            trace("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void trace(String msg) {
        toast(msg);
    }

    public void toast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void remove(final Cliente cliente) {
        this.clientes.remove(cliente);
    }

    public void add(final Cliente clientes) {
        this.clientes.add((Cliente) clientes);
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return clientes.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup2) {
        try {
            Cliente cliente = clientes.get(position);

            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout.linha_cliente, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvNome = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvRazaoSocialNome);
                holder.tvTelefone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvTelefone);
                holder.tvEmail = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(id.tvEmail);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.tvNome.setText(cliente.getNome());
            holder.tvTelefone.setText(cliente.getTelefone());
            holder.tvEmail.setText(cliente.getEmail());

            return convertView;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            trace("Erro: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvNome;
        public TextView tvTelefone;
        public TextView tvEmail;
    }

}
```

Comment: O que é esse `setListAdapter(adapter);`?

Comment: @Fernando é um método de `ListActivity`, que é a especialização de `Activity` que o OP está usando para exibir a lista.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja dentro do Adapter.

Mude o bloco,

```
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}
```

para

```
public int getCount() {
    return clientes.size();
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Obrigado cara!

Answer (score 0):

Tens de declarar a tua `ListView` e adicionar o adaptador a mesma:

```
ListView tua_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
tua_list_view.setListAdapter(adapter);
```